# Get percentage keywords show up in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database table full of tweets, and one of the columns is "subject". When I store the tweets in the database, I check for the existence of specific keywords, and whichever one the tweet matches, the subject is set to that word.

> **Keywords I'm checking for:** bieber, sucks
>
> **Tweet:** OMG I love Bieber!
>
> **Subject Stored:** bieber
>
> ---
>
> **Keywords I'm checking for:** bieber, sucks
>
> **Tweet:** This vacuum really sucks well!
>
> **Subject Stored:** sucks

On my site, I list out the share of the 'voice' on Twitter by these subjects. See below:

[image]

This will essentially be **(number of tweets with subject = 'KEYWORD HERE') / (total tweets in database)**.

The bar charts look like this:

```
<div class="barChart" data-value="2" data-title="eCircle"></div>
```

I'm not the best SQL statement and PHP to accomplish this. I can brute force it and go through each individual keyword, but I don't want to make that many calls to my database...seems wasteful.

Can I get back the total count, then the counts of each keyword in one big query? Like it comes back as an array or something?

**Bad Attempt:**

```
<?php
    include 'php/Connect.php';
    $totalTweets = 0;
    
    $ct = new Connect();
    $con = $ct->connect();
    $sql_query = 
        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tweets";
    $res = mysql_query($sql_query, $con);
    
    if (!$con | !$res) {
        echo "Problems connecting...";
    }
    
    else {
        mysql_close($con);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $totalTweets = $row['count(*)'];
        }
    }
    
    $sql_query = 
        "SELECT COUNT(*), subject FROM tweets
            WHERE subject = 'KEYWORD HERE'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql_query, $con);
    
    if (!$con | !$res) {
        echo "Problems connecting...";
    }
    
    else {
        mysql_close($con);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $firstKeyword = $row['subject'];
            $firstKeywordCount = $row['count(*)'];
        }
    }
    
    echo("<div class='barChart' data-value='".($firstKeywordCount/$totalTweets*100)."' data-title='$firstKeyword'></div>");
    
    // CONTINUE THIS UNTIL ALL KEYWORDS/SUBJECTS HAVE BEEN DONE
?>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Editing now. One moment.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: I'll work on that after I figure out this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Hm, if you have low level access, a `myisam_ftdump -c` works rather nicely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do 2 queries?

```
select subject, count(*) as numTweets from tweets group by subject;
select count(*) as totalTweets from tweets;
```

Comment: That seems to work. Thanks! I can just condense it to one by calculating the total count using the values from the first statement. Many thanks!